# :after transition doesn't work

Tags: css

Why transition doesn't work in the pseudo element :after/:before.

I just trying to put this in my css, but no, doesn't work.

```
.edicao-fotos-2 li a:hover{
transition:0.6s;
-o-transition:0.6s;
-ms-transition:0.6s;
-moz-transition:0.6s;
-webkit-transition:0.6s;
}

.edicao-fotos-2 li a:hover:after{
content: '';
width:244px;
height:243px;
background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
position:absolute;
top:-228px;
left:0;
transition:0.6s;
-o-transition:0.6s;
-ms-transition:0.6s;
-moz-transition:0.6s;
-webkit-transition:0.6s;
}
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have any default values for `.edicao-fotos-2 li a:after`.

```
/**
 * example values:
 * this will animate width and height
 */
.edicao-fotos-2 a:after {
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.edicao-fotos-2 li a:hover:after{
    content: '';
    width:244px;
    height:243px;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    position:absolute;
    top:-228px;
    left:0;

    -webkit-transition:0.6s;
       -moz-transition:0.6s;
        -ms-transition:0.6s;
         -o-transition:0.6s;
            transition:0.6s;
}
```

If you don't apply default values, the browser won't know how to start your animation.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4a7ex/)

Note: You should also write your transition rules beginning with the vendor prefixes, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

All [works fine](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EtgwJ) in `Chrome 32`. May be the problem is in `order` and `value` syntax. Try another order and add not only delay value:

```
-o-transition: all 0.6s;
-ms-transition: all 0.6s;
-moz-transition: all 0.6s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.6s;
transition: all 0.6s;
```

Change all on your property.